# Extract part of text using bash on a large file

Tags: bash

I have huge log file where I want to extract part of the log which looks like this:
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10  zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10  zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10  zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
....
This is a huge file and this yValues and zValues are repeated throughout.
Opening the file is very slow, so I am trying to extract this part of the text only.
If I do grep yValues, it still gives the whole line and so file saved is still a large file.
How can this be done using bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` has a `-o`/`--only-matching` option to do what you want:

```
$ grep --only-matching 'yValues:[0-9]\+' <<EOF
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10 zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10 zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
----TEXT NOT NEEDED--- yValues:10 zValues:1254 ----TEXT NOT NEEDED---
EOF
yValues:10
yValues:10
yValues:10
```

Comment: This is a log file, let's call it log.txt How would I apply your code on the file.

Comment: `grep --only-matching 'yValues:[0-9]\+' log.txt`

Comment: grep --only-matching 'yValues:[0-9]\+' log.txt  this worked